# AWS Maintenance - How to manage updates for Java, Tomcat and MySQL?

Tags: java, mysql, tomcat, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

New versions (minor versions) of Java, Tomcat and MySQL are released on a regular basis.
Does Amazon do these updates for you or do you have to do these updates on your own?
From my reading of AWS Maintenance documentations it seems like they do these through scheduled maintenances. But I'm not 100% sure. Can someone please confirm?
And if there are some best-practices around these, I'd love to know.

Answer (score 2):

It depends. If you use any of the managed services, they do often do upgrades (Like RDS).

If you are using a standard EC2 instance, they wont have access to your instance, so you are responsible for keeping packages upgraded.